# How to save back in the workspace from Power Bi embed?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

Using this code Power BI can be embed in edit mode.
{
if (firstRender)
{
var result = new PowerBIEmbedConfig();

```
        // Authenticate using created credentials
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;

        authenticationResult = await DoAuthentication();

        var tokenCredentials =
            new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(
            new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com/"), tokenCredentials))
        {
            var report = 
                await client.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(
                    new Guid(workspaceId), 
                    new Guid(reportId));

            var generateTokenRequestParameters =
                    new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "Edit", allowSaveAs: true);

            var tokenResponse = 
                await client.Reports.GenerateTokenAsync(
                    new Guid(workspaceId), 
                    new Guid(reportId), 
                    generateTokenRequestParameters);  

            result.EmbedToken = tokenResponse;
            result.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
            result.Id = report.Id.ToString();

            await Interop.CreateReport(
                JSRuntime,
                PowerBIElement,
                tokenResponse.Token,
                report.EmbedUrl,
                report.Id.ToString());    
        }
```

But how do use this embed container to write back in workspace and save it for future reference.

any code or Document reference

Comment: Are you able to embed the report in `edit` mode ? If, yes then you can save the report using `report.save()` or `report.saveAs()` API. On the other hand, you can also save the report from the UI, In the file option -> Save and it will save the report in the workspace.

Comment: LMK if the issue still persists.

Comment: the issue is still there

Comment: You need to reframe your question with more details. Are you facing any error while saving the report to workspace ?? Also  add some snapshots that will be helpful for anyone to understand.